# Mocha on Ruby: Check a stubbed function called once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-mocha

It should be straight forward, but it doesn't work for me.

I'm stubbing a function call, and I want to make sure it is called once, so I did:

```
MyClass.stubs(:record).returns(true).expect(:record).once
MyClass.run
```

but I keep getting:

```
expected exactly once, not yet invoked: allowed any number of times, invoked once: MyClass.record(any_parameters).record(any_parameters)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to set expectations for 2 separate invocations on `record`?

`stubs` is just a syntactic sugar for `expects`, specifying that you expect an invocation zero or more times.

You could probably rewrite your example as such:

```
MyClass.expects(:record).returns(true)
```

Keep in mind that `expects` is by default implying the `once` part although you could add it if you think that it adds to your code's clarity.